# Como guardar datos en una bbdd de wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo una pequeña duda, estoy haciendo un proyecto en wordpress y tengo varios formularios con inputs que deseo guardar en la base de datos pero no se cual es la manera mas optima de hacerlo (con php) y en que tablas guardar los datos. Podría hacerlo con contact form7 pero me gustaría hacerlo con php ya que puedo personalizar varias opciones que necesito y de otra manera pues me resultará mas difícil. Para simplificar el ejemplo pues imagínense que deseo guardar el id del usuario (de forma que si se da de baja eliminar el registro), nombre y una descripción.

¿alguna idea de como puedo hacer eso?

Un saludo  y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas para hacerlo, podrías crear un `Custom Post Type` y usar la función `wp_insert_post` para tomar los datos de un formulario y guardarlos en un nuevo post, un ejemplo seria algo asi:

```
$my_case = array(
        'post_title' => $_POST['title']',
        'post_content' => '$_POST['content']'
    );

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $create_case = wp_insert_post( $my_case );

    }
```

Puedes leer mas de `wp_insert_post` [aquí](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).

Esta seria la forma mas fácil, también puedes usar un plugin e incluso los formularios de ACF, (Awesome Custom Fields) Plugin.

Otra forma seria usando la clase global `$wpdb` obteniendo los valores de sus inputs y agregándolos con `$wpdb->insert` esta opción no suelo usarlo, ya que generalmente prefiero modificar la DB tan poco como me sea posible, así que recomendaría guardarlos en un post type, ya que seria mas fácil obtener sus datos para su uso después.

Si aun así quieres probar ese método puedes leer mas [aqui](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).